# Downloading RxSwift.framework binary at "Hashimoto.1"

Tags: carthage

Quick question. Just did:

```
carthage update --platform iOS
```

Then this shows in the console:

```
*** Cloning RxSwift
*** Downloading RxSwift.framework binary at "Hashimoto.1"
```

I can not find any information on what `Hashimoto.1` is, but maybe you know what Carthage is doing when it prints `Downloading <NameOfFramework>.framework binary at`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a release name from GitHub. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/releases/tag/3.3.1